# update rows using inner join posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables users and countries, and i'm trying to set the country.name with users.country_name for all countries with null name.

**Schema :**

[image]

```
// Creating tables
Table users as U {
  id int [pk, increment] // auto-increment
  full_name varchar
  created_at timestamp
  country_code int
  country_name varchar
}

Table countries {
  code int [pk]
  name varchar
  continent_name varchar
 }
```

> Ref: U.country_code > countries.code

**QUERY**

```
update c set c.name = u.country_name from
countries as c inner join users as u 
on c.code = u.country_code 
where c.name is null;
```

Error :
**DBSQLException: SQL Error [42P01]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the correct update join syntax and also remove the alias from the LHS of the `SET` clause:

```
update countries c
set name = u.country_name
from users as u 
where c.code = u.country_code and c.name is null;
```

Comment: can i reach the same result using inner join?

Comment: Postgres doesn't support an explicit update join as some other databases do.  You either have to use my answer or perhaps express the update using a subquery.